# How to change Schema Similarity to Classic Similarity in Solr 6.3

Tags: solr, similarity

Is there anyway to change from Schema similarity to Classic similarity in Solr 6.3

Answer (score 1):

You can do global change or by individual fields. For global change add the following line to your schema.xml or manage schema

```
<similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity" />
```

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <schema name="MySchema" version="1.6">
  <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity" />
   ...
```

For individual fields

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
  <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity"/>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do that in each field you declare (see `similarity` below):

```
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
      <similarity class="solr.ClassicSimilarityFactory"/>
   </fieldType>
```

Comment: Thanks. After this change, there is no change in scoring. Still it is showing Schemasimilarity in debug query. And also, there is no change in result order.